# Storage location of "adb_keys"

Tags: adb, storage, authorization

I have a Galaxy s3 (I9300) that has a broken touch screen (display is fine). I therefore can not click the authorization dialog that pops up when I try to access the device via `adb` on any ROMs above Android 4.2 as they require authorization to access the device via `adb`.

On 4.2 and 4.3 of the stock ROMs, I am able to copy my `~/.android/adbkey.pub`  file from my machine to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` on the device via CWM recovery and gain access. I have tried this with `LineageOS 14` which is on Android 7.1.1 and I still don't get access. I am wondering where the `adb_keys` file is located on android 7.1.1 so I can do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Android 4.2 when public key authentication was [added](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/f4ed516643ee8ed3a59ad1a8048f7ce5f47f93fb) to ADB, up to latest release 10, there are only two possible locations for `adb_keys` on stock Android:

> On the device, vendors public keys are installed at build time in `/adb_keys`. User-installed keys are stored in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`.

So is the case with Android [7.1.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-7.1.1_r1/adb/adb_auth_client.cpp#40):

```
static const char *key_paths[] = {
    "/adb_keys",
    "/data/misc/adb/adb_keys",
    NULL
};
```

First one is only found on `userdebug`/`eng` ROMs. Also on debuggable builds, you can set `ro.adb.secure` to `0` to *"allow `adbd` to connect without authentication"*. However *"`user` builds filter out `PRODUCT_ADB_KEYS`, so no `/adb_keys` will be included"*. <sup>([Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/README.md))</sup>

So the RSA public keys added to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` should work. Make sure proper ownership (`system:shell`), mode (`0640`) and SELinux label (`u:object_r:adb_keys_file:s0`) are set on the file and restart `adbd` after adding key(s). Also check correct line endings (use `dos2unix`) after adding key(s) and make sure the right private key pair is available to `adb` server on PC. Path is `~/.android/` on Linux and `%userprofile%\.android\` on Windows, or add the key filename/directory to `ADB_VENDOR_KEYS` environment variable.

---

**RELATED:**

- [Why “adb root” does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526)

Comment: How do I apply a SELinux label to a file? `semanage` doesn't exist on Android, or at least my OnePlus 6.

Comment: @Nowaker use [`chcon`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A218526+chcon). SELinux policy is not configurable on Android devices, unlike PCs. So there's no `semanage`.