# How to allow ADB on phone if there is a Lock Screen and Screen is not responding + black

Tags: adb, root-access, lock-screens, broken-screen

How to allow ADB on a rooted Android Samsung J3(2016) if said phone has a broken display(black/unresponsive)?

P.S - ADB is enabled. Just not allowed.

Comment: Honestly, you can't... You must allow it via the screen once, until then you can't really do anything with adb.

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171934/android-7-1-1-storage-location-of-adb-keys).

Answer (score 1):

theres no way to do it.

only if your screen on, you could broke-lock with a ByPass and then allow it