# Password protect adb

Tags: adb

Looking for an option to password protect adb so I can enable it all the time and accept all connections.

In the event if I break my phone's screen and I need to pull my files out this would really be helpful.

Comment: `adb` supports RSA key authentication (if configured) which is far stronger than a password: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219320/218526

Comment: You don't need to "acept all connections". Just make sure to backup the adb authentication keys from your PC once you have accepted them on device. Then nothing can go wrong if you ever need adb access.

Comment: ... nothing except https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226666