# How to transfer USB debugging authorization permission from one laptop to another?

Tags: usb-debugging, android-sdk

I have an Android device with Android 5.0. I turned on USB debugging and connected it to one laptop. The android device displayed a pop-up for USB debugging authorization, I allowed it. After a few days, I accidentally broke the Android device screen, it's not sensing any touch input and the screen display is quite broken. I have another laptop, and now I want, connect to that Android device to USB debugging.

- How do I do it?
- Is it possible to force "USB Debug authorization" from the laptop side?
- Are USB Debugging Permission given to one laptop stored/saved in that laptop, like a file in the `android-sdk` folder or `platform-tools folder`, so that I can copy that file to another laptop and make it works, OR transfer RSA fingerprint, or any other ideas?

Comment: as for why need another-laptop, why not just use one-laptop already with usb debug authorized permission, cause that laptop has only 4gb ram and very slow processor. laptop-2 is more better

Comment: Check [Android ADB Key Not Working](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226669/3573) and [Storage location of "adb_keys"](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219320/3573)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply copy the adb private adb public key file to a new computer or a different user profile:

```
# Windows
%USERPROFILE%\.android\adbkey
%USERPROFILE%\.android\adbkey.pub

# Linux/MacOS
~/.android/adbkey
~/.android/adbkey.pub
```

Afterwards you may have to restart the local adb server if it is running. You can do so executing `adb kill-server`.
Afterwards the new adb keys should be used and you can open adb connection to your phone.