# How to authorize unauthorized device via Android Debug Bridge (adb) for non-working screen stuck at boot-time pin prompt for Pixel 5a?

Tags: adb, broken-screen

Android 13. Basically, my screen doesn't work anymore but it works otherwise. Previously I was able to set up AirDroid cast through a painful process with an accessibility talkback feature.

My device rebooted though and required a boot-time pin. For some reason, I was getting a version mismatch error (from the client having v41/platform-tools_r33.0.3-windows and the server being v40). Now I can't log in anymore due to it being unauthorized.

I used this command to log in I think it wouldn't take my fingerprint initially. Then any unlocks were OK via fingerprint.

I downloaded v40/platform-tools_r28.0.1. While it got rid of the mismatch error, I think in the process my keys disappeared.

Now when I run ADB devices in either version, it says unauthorized for my phone. I tried kill-server and restart-server in both versions.

Is there any way to generate a key via ADB in windows 11? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android ADB Key Not Working](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226666/android-adb-key-not-working)

Comment: Just restore adb keys from a system backup.

Comment: @Robert unfortunately I do not have a backup.