# Bypass ADB Unauthorized

Tags: adb, root-access, recovery-mode, twrp

I have `hero2ltechn` or Samsung s7 edge with broken screen, already rooted and with custom twrp, i able to do root command.

i only have access to adb recovery mode....

so i want enable adb from twrp with

```
echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >>/system/build.prop
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >>/system/build.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage,adb" >>/system/build.prop"
```

now my adb is works on the device , but unauthorized.

from here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219320 says, need to push `adb_keys` to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` or `/adb_keys`

i've already do that. still unauthorized... help me

this is what i try :

```
C:\Users\Administrator>adb -s ec525f2c shell
~ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:su:s0

~ # setprop
usage: setprop <key> <value>
~ # getprop
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-filter]: [verify-at-runtime]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-filter]: [verify-at-runtime]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant]: [cortex-a53]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant]: [kryo]
[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[fbe.data.wrappedkey]: [true]
[init.svc.adbd]: [stopping]
[init.svc.recovery]: [running]
[init.svc.set_permissive]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ueventd]: [running]
[keyguard.no_require_sim]: [true]
[mtp.crash_check]: [0]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.change]: [net.bt.name]
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [libart]
[persist.sys.root_access]: [1]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[ro.allow.mock.location]: [1]
[ro.arch]: [msm8996]
[ro.baseband]: [msm]
[ro.board.platform]: [msm8996]
[ro.boot.ap_serial]: [0xc2bb0abc]
[ro.boot.baseband]: [msm]
[ro.boot.boot_recovery]: [1]
[ro.boot.bootdevice]: [624000.ufshc]
[ro.boot.bootloader]: [SCV33KDU1CRH2]
[ro.boot.carrierid.param.offset]: [9438268]
[ro.boot.carrierid]: []
[ro.boot.cp_debug_level]: [0x55FF]
[ro.boot.cp_reserved_mem]: [off]
[ro.boot.debug_level]: [0x4f4c]
[ro.boot.emmc_checksum]: [3]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [qcom]
[ro.boot.hmac_mismatch]: [0]
[ro.boot.revision]: [15]
[ro.boot.sales.param.offset]: [9438272]
[ro.boot.sales_code]: [XSG]
[ro.boot.sec_atd.tty]: [/dev/ttyHSL0]
[ro.boot.security_mode]: [1526595585]
[ro.boot.selinux]: [permissive]
[ro.boot.serialno]: [ec525f2c]
[ro.boot.ucs_mode]: [0]
[ro.boot.warranty_bit]: [1]
[ro.bootimage.build.date.utc]: [1592918780]
[ro.bootimage.build.date]: [Tue Jun 23 13:26:20 UTC 2020]
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [samsung/omni_hero2qltechn/hero2qltechn:6.0.1/MOB31K/17:eng/test-keys]
[ro.bootloader]: [SCV33KDU1CRH2]
[ro.bootmode]: [unknown]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [default]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [0]
[ro.build.date]: [Tue Jun 23 13:24:59 UTC 2020]
[ro.build.display.id]: [omni_hero2qltechn-eng 6.0.1 MOB31K 17 test-keys]
[ro.build.flavor]: [omni_hero2qltechn-eng]
[ro.build.host]: [f13e74e204de]
[ro.build.id]: [MOB31K]
[ro.build.tags]: [test-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [eng]
[ro.build.user]: [jenkins]
[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.base_os]: []
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [17]
[ro.build.version.preview_sdk]: []
[ro.build.version.release]: [6.0.1]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [23]
[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2016-11-05]
[ro.carrier]: [unknown]
[ro.chipname]: [MSM8996]
[ro.com.android.dataroaming]: [true]
[ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist]: [GoogleGuest]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase]: [android-google]
[ro.config.alarm_alert]: [Argon.ogg]
[ro.config.notification_sound]: [pixiedust.ogg]
[ro.config.ringtone]: [Ring_Synth_04.ogg]
[ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge]: [0]
[ro.debuggable]: [1]
[ro.hardware.keystore]: [msm8996]
[ro.hardware]: [qcom]
[ro.kernel.android.checkjni]: [1]
[ro.lcd_brightness]: [162]
[ro.lcd_min_brightness]: [0]
[ro.modversion]: [OmniROM-6.0.1-20200623-hero2qltechn-HOMEMADE]
[ro.omni.device]: [hero2qltechn]
[ro.omni.version]: [6.0.1-20200623-hero2qltechn-HOMEMADE]
[ro.product.board]: [msm8996]
[ro.product.brand]: [samsung]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.device]: [hero2qltechn]
[ro.product.locale]: [en-US]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-G9350]
[ro.product.name]: [hero2qltezc]
[ro.revision]: [15]
[ro.secure]: [0]
[ro.serialno]: [ec525f2c]
[ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode]: [1]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [640]
[ro.twrp.boot]: [1]
[ro.twrp.sar]: [false]
[ro.twrp.version]: [3.4.0-0]
[ro.url.legal]: [http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html]
[ro.wifi.channels]: []
[ro.zygote]: [zygote32]
[service.adb.root]: [1]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.ffs.ready]: [1]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
[twrp.action_complete]: [0]
[twrp.crash_counter]: [0]
~ # getprop|grep adb
[init.svc.adbd]: [stopping]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[service.adb.root]: [1]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
~ # getprop|grep gebug
~ # setprop ro.adb.secure 0
~ # getprop|grep debug
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[ro.boot.cp_debug_level]: [0x55FF]
[ro.boot.debug_level]: [0x4f4c]
[ro.debuggable]: [1]
~ # reboot

C:\Users\Administrator>adb devices
List of devices attached
42008e67aaad4400        device


C:\Users\Administrator>adb kill-server

C:\Users\Administrator>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
42008e67aaad4400        device
ec525f2c        unauthorized


C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: ['adb devices' says unauthorized in TWRP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528833/9165920)

Comment: still unauthorized